# SSRS - Is it possible to use parameters as variable for a query

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

Is it possible to pass a parameter as a string into a query? For example, I want a **single report** to be able to select whether null values are or are not returned **using a report parameter**.

```
select * from dbo.mytable
where myColumn is null

select * from dbo.mytable
where myColumn is not null
```

I would like to substitute where statement with a report parameter: @columnNull

Available Values for @columnNull: 'is null', 'is not null'

Query with parameter:
`select * from dbo.mytable where myColumn @columnNull`

This doesn't work as it apparently wants an operator between myColumn and @columnNull. If this is not possible, is there some other equivalent method I am not thinking. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - you can use the Dataset Expression to use your parameter as text.

```
="SELECT * FROM dbo.mytable WHERE myColumn " & Parameters!columnNull.Value
```

This will build the dataset with your parameters text.

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.mytable WHERE myColumn is not null
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect. Thanks! Can't believe I hadn't thought of that. This will come in handy.

Answer (score 0):

Instead use a `bit` parameter and a `OR`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM dbo.MyTable
WHERE (MyColumn IS NULL AND @MyParameter = 0)
   OR (MyColumn IS NOT NULL AND @MyParameter = 1)
OPTION (RECOMPILE);
```

The `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` might not be needed, but queries like this tend to benefit from it due to poor query caching.

Otherwise you would need to use dynamic SQL, which I would suggest you should not be using (based on the syntax you were trying to use) and SSRS normally needs a little "pushing" to accept dynamic statements.

Comment: Thanks!  I tried to upvote, but I am too new

Comment: If it answers the question, the accept it as the solution, @BrandonM .